# how to parse Bing CSE data - How to receive sub_title from json

Tags: python, json, parsing, bing, bing-api

I'm using Bing cse to receive information in my program and I am having trouble prasing the whole bing search data.

there is a json format example:

```
{u'Web': [{
    u'Description': u"Discription", 
    u'DisplayUrl': u'DisplayedUrl', 
    u'ID': u'Id', 
    u'Title': u'Title', 
    u'Url': u'Url', 
    u'__metadata': {
        u'type': u'WebResult', 
        u'uri': u"https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/v1/ExpandableSearchResultSet(guid'XXXXX')/Web?$skip=0&$top=1"
    }
}]}
```

I have DisplayUrl, Title, discription but i cant figure out how to take the sub_title of the query.
the sub_title is the short discription below the title(not always appears)

the search results in "real" bing search is displayed in the following way:

Title
DisplayUrl
Sub_Title
Discription

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you saved that structure as the variable `foo`, the following python code will iterate over the list of items (which you only gave one example of), and print out the values for each item:

```
for item in foo.get(u'Web', []):  # Iterate over the list under the dictionary key "Web"
    print item.get(u'Title'), item.get(u'DisplayUrl'), item.get(u'Sub_Title'), item.get(u'Description')

Title DisplayedUrl None Discription
```

You will notice that item.get(u'Sub_Title') will return `None` in this case, but would return valid data if the dictionary contains that key.

Comment: Yeah, thats my problem.. i don't receive any sub title in the results structure.. I might need to configure something in order to get it? If i do, what I need to configure? Thanks

Comment: I looked a bit in the bing search api schema and and there is no mention of sub_title. I.E https://skydrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=9C9479871FBFA822!109&app=Word&authkey=!ACvyZ_MNtngQyCU --- page 7